# Laravel 8 после авторизации перекидывает на css файл

Tags: laravel

после авторизации перекидывает на сss файл - css/app.css
в LoginController убираю intended и без проблем перекидывает на установленный роут, но дело в том, что этот метод мне нужен

Comment: Опишите проблему подробно, приведите код.

Comment: Авторизуюсь в системе и сразу перекидывает на файл app.css. Авторизация  из под коробки laravel 8,  
Route::name('user.')->group(function () {
    Route::get('/login', function () {
        if (Auth::check()) {
            return redirect(route('main'));
        }
        return view('auth.login');
    })->name('login');
    Route::post('/login', [\App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController::class, 'login']); маршрут входа

Comment: public function login(Request $request){
         if(Auth::check()){
            return redirect(route('main'));
        }
        $formFields = $request->only(['email','password'],'verified', true);
        if(Auth::attempt($formFields)){
            return redirect()->intended(route('main'));
        } код контроллера LoginController, заметил, что если убрать метод intended, то после авторизации перекидывает нормально по маршруту

Comment: http://project1/js/app.js после авторизации перекидывает на этот файл

Comment: Решено, в шаблоне ссылалось на пустые файлы, просто удалил их

Answer (score 0):

Решено, в шаблоне ссылалось на пустые файлы, просто удалил их